# How to write to an OutputStream directly using Stringtemplate 4.x?

Tags: java, outputstream, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

I don't want to call `.render()` and build extremely large `Strings` from some of my templates. In previous versions you could write to an `OutputStream` directly instead of having to render the entire template to a `String` and then write that out.

I tried using `ST.write()` with an instance of `NoIndentWriter` but that produces no output.

How do you write directly to an `OutputStream` using the latest version of `Stringtemplate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `AutoIndentWriter` if you want to maintain the standard formatting.

```
ST template = group.getInstanceOf("YourTemplate");
OutputStreamWriter osWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(stream);
STWriter stWriter = new AutoIndentWriter(osWriter);
template.write(stWriter);
osWriter.flush();
```